# How to bind input of type checkbox to v-model of child component in `vuejs` to a parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can input of type checkbox present in `child component` be bonded to `v-model` on the `parent component`?

Required Component Way -

Parent-

```
<button v-if="checkedNames">Confirm</button> //show this button if 1 checkbox is selected
<div v-model="checkedNames" >
<child-component  v-for="person in collection" :key="person.id"  
:person="person"><child-component>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    checkedNames: [],
    collection: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Jack', items:[{id:100,name:"Pen",quantity:5}]},
      {id: 2, name: 'John', items:[{id:200,name:"Pen",quantity:10},
        {id:201,name:"Paper",quantity:100,}]},
      {id: 3, name: 'Mike', items:[{id:300,name:"Pen",quantity:20}]},
    ]
  }
})
```

Child-

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in person.items" :key="i">
<input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :value="item.name" >
<label :for="item.id">{{item.name}}</label>
<input type="number" :id="i" :value="item.quantity" >
<label :for="i">{{item.quantity}}</label>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '...',
  props:{person:Object}
})
```

How to send the item id, quantity and main id if the checkbox is selected to the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Using v-model on Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)
2. `new Vue()` is to use only to create top-level Vue instance (usually called `vm` or `app`). Components used as a child elements must be registered instead - [Component Registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)
3. Always use `:key` with `v-for` - [Maintaining State](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

```js
Vue.component('checkboxes', {
  props: ['value', 'options'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <template v-for="item in optionsWithKey">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="item.key" :value="item.name" v-model="model" :key="item.key">
      <label :for="item.key">{{item.name}}</label>
    </template>
  </div>
  `,
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() { return this.value },
      set(newValue) { this.$emit('input', newValue) }
    },
    optionsWithKey() {
      return this.options.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        key: "checkbox_"+ item.id
      }))
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedNames: [],
    options:[
      {id: 1, name: 'Jack'},
      {id: 2, name: 'John'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Mike'},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <checkboxes v-model="checkedNames" :options="options">
  </checkboxes>
  <pre>{{ checkedNames }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try it...

child:

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :value="item.name" :change="$emit('valueChecked',item.name)">
```

And in parent:

```
<child-component @valuChecked="getValue"><child-component>

methods:{
getValue(value){
 this.checkedNames.push(value);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

See if [this](https://codepen.io/vanechka222/pen/ZEyBmPx?editors=1010) helps

```
// parent template

  <child-component @update:checked-names="updateCheckedNames">
  <child-component>

// parent

  data() {
    return {
      checkedNames: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateCheckedNames(name) {
      if (this.checkedNames.includes(name)) {
        const index = this.checkedNames.indexOf(name);
        this.checkedNames.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        this.checkedNames.push(name);
      }
    }
  }

// child template

  <div v-for="item in collection">
    <input type="checkbox"
      :id="item.id"
      :value="item.name"
      @click="$emit('update:checked-names', item.name)"> // emit here
    <label :for="item.id">
      {{item.name}}</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Click event is not the only way a checkbox can be changed – tab and enter keys can be used, or the browser can even remember the previous state. I believe the change event is safer to use